# Conditionally Update a DevExpress ASPX GridView Image based on row value

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

How can I conditionally put an image into a cell on my ASPxGridView. For example; if Column1 is above 1000 I would like to see 'above.png' on Column2, if below 1000 i want to see 'below.png' on Column2.

Here is the markup for my ASPXGridView:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" KeyFieldName="pkCalisan" Width="100%" > 
    <Columns> 
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn 
            FieldName="ID" 
            ReadOnly="True" 
            VisibleIndex="0"> 
                <EditFormSettings Visible="False" /> 
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>     
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Price" VisibleIndex="1"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn> 
        <dx:GridViewDataImageColumn VisibleIndex="2"></dx:GridViewDataImageColumn> 
    </Columns> 
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Thanks..

Comment: You have to manage to code in GridView_RowDataBound event. Could you provide your GridView aspx code?

Comment: <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" KeyFieldName="pkCalisan" Width="100%" >

<Columns>

<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0">

<EditFormSettings Visible="False" />

</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Price" VisibleIndex="1">

</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

<dx:GridViewDataImageColumn VisibleIndex="2">

</dx:GridViewDataImageColumn>

</Columns>

</dx:ASPxGridView>

Comment: I've updated the original question with your markup - better than posting as a comment. There's a worked example here: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q149237.aspx - you can replace the control and conditions with whatever you want in the GridCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a custom image control inside the column's DataItemTemplate and manage the image's properties (visibility or image URL) at runtime.

See the [E2270](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2270.aspx) Example that illustrates how to manage the hyperlink's properties in a similar scenario.